# Best way to save many changes in EF without locking the DB

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I've several services using Entity Framework to save many changes in a DataBase.

When they're executed in the IIS it goes really quick but when I'm in debug mode and running it on my development computer it takes a couple of minutes and I've see that all the rest queries crash (even if they are not over the same table I'm updating).

So I've thought I'm not doing this the way I should 8-)

My code is something like this:

```
public void CancelOrders(ObservableCollection<long> idOrders)
    {
        Model.Entities context = new Model.Entities();

        var query = from orders in context.ORDERS.Include("CUSTOMERS")
                    where idOrders.Contains(orders.id_order)
                    select orders;

        foreach (var order in query)
        {
            foreach (var customer in order.CUSTOMERS)
            {
                customer.served = false;
            }
            context.ORDERS.DeleteObject(order);
        }

        context.SaveChanges();

    }
```

The problems come when it runs the context.SaveChanges()... it use to be around 2000 rows and it takes a while to finish (and meanwhile NOBODY can use the same database).

Should I make a more frecuent context.SaveChanges()??? May I use a different approach??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't need your deletes to be transasctional, then you can just call `SaveChanges()` more frequently by adding it to the end of either the outer `foreach` loop or both the inner and the outer.

I would suspect that you would at least want deleting an order and updating the customers to be transactional, so I would suggest only putting it within the outer `foreach` loop.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I call SaveChanges() more frequently... will the database be locked??? Or SQL Server will be able to answer other queries meanwhile??? Thanks :-)

Comment: @zapico: The tables are locked because of the transaction created by `SaveChanges`. Because your batches will be smaller, the transactions will be shorter-lived and the database will be able to respond to queries using the affected tables in between them.

Comment: Ok I'll try it by making transactions every 100 "customers" change because here is the real "big problem" ;-). Thanks so much.